# CouchDB link multiple documents

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

Is it possible to link multiple documents in one view.

Eg :

```
{
  "_id" : "0b86008d8490abf0b7e4f15f0c6a463b",
  "name" : "copenhagen"}
{
  "_id" : "8986008d8490abf0b7e4f15f0c6a333b",
  "player" : "Mark"
}
{
  "_id" : "4b86008d8490abf0b7e4f15f0c6a463c",
  "location" : { "uuid" : "0b86008d8490abf0b7e4f15f0c6a463b"},
  "player" : { "uuid" : "8986008d8490abf0b7e4f15f0c6a333b"},
  "session" : "9876"
}
```

I want a view to include location document as well as the player document.

View :

```
  "fetchByLocationAndPlayer": {
       "map": "function(doc) {    if (doc.session) {  emit(doc.session, { _id : **doc.location.uuid** });     } }"
   }
```

In the query I use includedocs = true.

How do I emit multiple documents corresponding to multiple keys in one document?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Just use two emits instead of one

```
emit(doc.session, {_id:doc.location.uuid});
emit(doc.session,{_id:doc.player.uuid});
```

[Couch db wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Linked_documents) lists yet another way of doing this by iterating over the array and emitting linked docs one by one.

Comment: Thanks! It works. Is there any way to limit the json emitted by the linked document? It emits the entire linked document as a doc attribute.

Comment: @Bhoomi unfortunately no. You can not pick the fields that will be emitted by the linked document. Come to think of it it would be a nice feature to have.

Comment: You can use a list function to lint the total output of the view: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/couchapp/ddocs.html?highlight=list%20function#list-functions